# How can I make my UIPickerView Multiline in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView how can I make it multiline? I have some long text.

Here is my code.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    var returnResult: String = ""
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
    //This picker has long text
        let position: UInt = UInt(row)
        returnResult = list.objectAtIndex(position).Description.Value;
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        returnResult =  questionTwoOptions[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 3 {
        returnResult = questionThreeOptions[row]
    } else {
        returnResult = ""
    }
    print(returnResult)
    return returnResult
}
```

Here is my viewForRow methode

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44));
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    //view!.addSubview(label)
    return label;
}
```

Comment: Implement the `viewForRow` delegate method and return a `UILabel` as needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try like this with the custom view

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44));
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.text = arr[row]
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label;
}
```

If you have content that can take more than two lines you can also set the row height

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

Comment: I have 2 pickers in same screen. how can I use default title for 1 and custom view for another?

Comment: compare pickerView with both of the pickview outlet values then, create uiview accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 4

- Keep in mind a `UILabel` **is** a subclass of `UIView`.
- We are creating the views for the `UIPickerView`, other delegate methods that supply text to the views are now irrelevant.
- Change the `height:` parameter during the creation of the `UILabel` and adjust the `return 80.0` for row height, if even more space is required.
- Don't forget to set additional properties like text alignment.

First add the delegate method to indicate row height. Adjust to a value that looks best for your display purposes.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80.0
}
```

Next add the delegate method to supply the view.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label: UILabel

    if let view = view {
        label = view as! UILabel
    }
    else {
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerView.frame.width, height: 400))
    }

    label.text = myTitleStrings[row]
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label
}
```

### Example with Attributed Text

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label: UILabel

    if let view = view {
        label = view as! UILabel
    }
    else {
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerView.frame.width, height: 400))
    }

    let title = myTitleStrings[row]
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                      NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18.0)!]
    label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to change the rowHeightForComponent (UIPickerView)

Something like:

```
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 70.0
    }
```

And you're going to be able to see it in multiline, all the rest you've done well.